# How can I update my table in C# with OOP?

Tags: c#, oop, oracle11g, crud

I have a program in C#/.net framework and currently implementing CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete).

Doing this program in Object Oriented Program (OOP) format.

So far I have implemented the Create, Read and Delete function and still working on Update. It seems that I have something to do with my code as I know my syntax are correct.

My table won't able to show the updated records. And/Or my table is not updating.

I have this project named `Enrollment` and ClassLibrary `Module`

**Enrollment**

**AddUser.cs**

```
public void ViewList() {
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table = userClass.AccountView();
    dtgRecord.DataSource = table;
}

public void UpdateList() {
    userClass.AccountUpdate(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text, txtPosition.Text);
    MessageBox.Show("Account updated!");
}

private void dtgRecord_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0) {
        DataGridViewRow row = this.dtgRecord.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        txtUsername.Text = row.Cells["username"].Value.ToString();
        txtPassword.Text = row.Cells["password"].Value.ToString();
        txtPosition.Text = row.Cells["position"].Value.ToString();
    }
}

private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    UpdateList();
}
```

**Module**

**UserClass.cs**

```
public void AccountUpdate(string username, string password, string position) {
    AccountID();
    result.Query = "Update tbl_account set (" + id + ", '" + username + "', '" + password + "', '" + position + "')";
    result.Transaction = true;
    result.ExecuteNonQuery();
    AccountCommit();
    result.Close();
}

public void AccountID() {
    int id = 101;
    result.Query = "Select id from tbl_account order by id asc";
    if (result.Execute()) {
        while (result.Read()) {
            id = result.GetInt("id");
            id++;
        }
    }
}

public void AccountCommit() {
    if (!result.Commit()) {
        result.Rollback();
    }
}
```

The rest of my codes are good and well coded. Every time I run and try to update my records, It always highlighting the `result.ExecuteNonQuery();` on AccountUpdate function.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks like you're missing column names in your update statement. That is, `Update tbl_account set(" + id + ",....` should become `Update tbl_account set(id = " + id + ",...`

Comment: I have AccountID code and I think that's not the problem. I tried that and still not working.

Comment: Valid t-sql update statement requires a format like Update FooTable SET ColumnName1 = 'value', ColumnName2 = 'value2'...` - where `ColumnName1` and ColumnName2` are columns on `FooTable`.  You're update statement is not specifying your column names you want to update - this is unrelated to getting an AccountId

Comment: On related note, `AccountID` is not how you generate an id for a new row in sql.  Have a read on how Identity columns work http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx You'll want to assign the id on insert for use in your update (see @iceburg's answer) as currently you'll end up always updating the last row in your table

Comment: Please do not use string concatenation to build SQL queries - use parametrized queries instead.

Comment: Ok. I think I made it wrong on update query and you guys correct, but still not working and it always highlighting the result.ExecuteNonQuery(); and showing this error: ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: Why are you not using just any ORM instead of direct SQL-queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void AccountUpdate(string id, string username, string password, string position) {
//remove it AccountID();
    result.Query="Update tbl_account set username='"+username+"', password='"+password+"', position='"+position+"' where id="+id;
//even your id is string if you remove the quote in your where clause, it will still treat as int
    result.Transaction = true;
    result.ExecuteNonQuery();
    AccountCommit();
    result.Close();
}
```

remove your accountID(); instead declare paramater string id and get the id value in your datagrid here is the code

```
string id;//declare it as global
private void dtgRecord_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0) {
        DataGridViewRow row = this.dtgRecord.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        id = row.Cells["id"].Value.ToString();
        txtUsername.Text = row.Cells["username"].Value.ToString();
        txtPassword.Text = row.Cells["password"].Value.ToString();
        txtPosition.Text = row.Cells["position"].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

and to update your data in datagrid call your the `ViewList function` like this

```
public void UpdateList() {
    userClass.AccountUpdate(id, txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text, txtPosition.Text);
    MessageBox.Show("Account updated!");
    ViewList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's missing the where clause too.

```
result.Query="Update tbl_account set username="+username+", password="+password+", position="+position+" where id="+id;
```

Comment: Yes, I think this query is correct, but it still not working. It always highlighting the `result.ExecuteNonQuery();` and showing this error: `ORA-00936: missing expression`

Comment: that (Oracle RDBMS) error means the SQL syntax is invalid. Do you have the correct table and column names?  Missing a comma somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, it looks like you have a wrapper, variable name `result`.  So you should write your code something like:

```
result.Query="Update tbl_account set username=@0, password=@1, position=@2 where id=@3";
result.Parameters = new Object[] { username, password, position, id };

    public int ExecuteNonQuery() {
        DbProviderFactory dbFact = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(conn.GetType().Namespace);
        using (DbCommand cmd = dbFact.CreateCommand()) {
            cmd.Connection = conn;

            cmd.CommandText = this.Query;
            for (int i = 0; i < Parameters.Length; i++) {
                var p = dbFact.CreateParameter();
                p.ParameterName = "@" + i;
                p.Value = Parameters[i];
                cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
            }

            return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```